# How can I animate my div to go from top to bottom whithout interfering with the content inside?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to show my div when a specific link is clicked.

And I want to animate my div sliding from top to the bottom when this function is called.

Just like on Android, when you push the bar and the content appears.

I would like to do it without interfering with the content inside the div.

How can I do that? Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/8qmj5tjx/

HTML

```
 <a class="respfc" href="#"><span class="sn">Click</span></a>

    <div class="persside">
    Text here
    <br><br>
    Text here
    <br><br>
    Text here
    <br><br>
    Text here
    <br><br>
    Text here
    <br><br>
    Text here
    <br><br>
    Text here
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div.persside {
    background-color: rgba(38,38,38,0.9);
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
 $( ".sn" ).click(function() {

  $(".persside").show();

});
```

Comment: You can do this by setting the position of the div above the visible screen and then animate it's position down. One issue you're going to run into though, is knowing the height of the visible screen and flowing your div content to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8qmj5tjx/3/)  You can use css3 [`transform: translateY(-100%)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [`transition: transform .3s ease`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)  and use Jquery to [`addCLass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) or [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)  active

```js
 $( ".sn" ).click(function() {
 
  $(".persside").addClass("active");

});
```

```css
    div.persside {
        background-color: rgba(38,38,38,0.9);
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        transition: transform .3s ease
    }
    div.persside.active {
        transform: translateY(0%)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="respfc" href="#"><span class="sn">Click</span></a>

<div class="persside">Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
</div>
```

The same result can be done with **Pure javascript** like this

```js
function toggleMe(){
    persside.classList.toggle("active")
}

var sn = document.querySelector(".sn"),
    persside = document.querySelector(".persside");

sn.addEventListener("click", toggleMe, false);
```

```css
    div.persside {
        background-color: rgba(38,38,38,0.9);
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        z-index: 10;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: translateY(-100%);
        transition: transform .3s ease
    }
    div.persside.active {
        transform: translateY(0%)
    }
```

```html
 <a class="respfc" href="#"><span class="sn">Click</span></a>

<div class="persside">Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
<br><br>
Text here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sn').click( function() { 
            $('.persside').toggle();
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/8qmj5tjx/1/

you can use `transform: translateY();` change the time `transition: 2s linear;` to what you want

```js
 $(".sn").click(function() {
   $(".persside").addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
div.persside {
  background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.9);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: 2s linear;
}
div.persside.active {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="respfc" href="#"><span class="sn">Click</span></a>

<div class="persside">Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here</div>
```

Or you can also use `top` first set position top `-100%` and on adding active class change the position top to `0`

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/8qmj5tjx/5/

```js
 $(".sn").click(function() {
   $(".persside").addClass('active');
 });
```

```css
div.persside {
  background-color: rgba(38, 38, 38, 0.9);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: -100%;
  transition: 2s linear;
}
div.persside.active {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="respfc" href="#"><span class="sn">Click</span></a>

<div class="persside">Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here
  <br>
  <br>Text here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making following changes, It give you advantage as you can set time as well as how much amount you want to show:

CSS:

```
height:0px;
//display:none;
```

Javascript:

```
$(".persside").animate({"height": $(window).height()},600);
```

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/8qmj5tjx/6/

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
div.persside {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS

```
$( ".sn" ).click(function() { 
  var tar =  $('.persside');
         tar.animate({top: tar.height()/2 - tar.outerHeight()/2}, {duration: 500, queue: false}); 
});
$(function(){
    $('.persside').css('top', ($('.persside').height() * -1)+ "px")
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8qmj5tjx/19/

Hope works as you need!